# number in the middle is more than neighbour

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

Given the array of integers, rearrange the array such that the elements are arranged in alternate order

`a1<a2>a3<a4>a5<a6>a7`

You can do this by first sorting it O(NLogN) and rearranging it. Is it possible to do this in O(n) time?

Comment: Yes it can be done in O(n). Do you want the answer or just a hint (as this is an interview question)?

Comment: Finally got the solution in O(N).

Comment: @AyushShukla Can you share your solution?

Comment: @HelderPereira Here it is!

Comment: @AyushShukla Thanks! Nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

Step 1 : Get the median of the array in O(n) time. We can do this by getting (n/2)th largest element by [QuickSelect](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array/) method.

Step 2 : Now Don't read this step, think about the solution, its pretty clear. Take the number got in the previous step as your pivot and do the first step of quickSort.

Step 3 : Now the elements on left of the median is less than the median and on the right, it is greater than the median.

Step 4 : Just take the elements from left and right alternatively and you will get the what we want!